# How to instantiate classes and their properties in F#

Tags: c#, f#, c#-to-f#

Follow Code C#:

```
var body = new CustomerRequest
{
    Method = "CREDIT_CARD",
    CreditCard = new Creditcard
    {
        ExpirationMonth = "06",
        ExpirationYear = "2022",
        Number = "4012001037141112",
        Cvc = "123"
    }
};
```

I'm new to F#, I can not instantiate classes like C#, See the code below in F#:

```
let body = CustomerRequest
(
    Method = "CREDIT_CARD"     // Help here
)
```

I can not convert C # to F #

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to use [named arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/parameters-and-arguments#named-arguments) to set properties of the classes you are constructing: the syntax is quite similar to C#. As for the level of indentation, you need to align with that of the first argument.

```
let body =
    CustomerRequest(
        Method = "CREDIT_CARD",
        CreditCard =
            Creditcard(
                ExpirationMonth = "06",
                ExpirationYear = "2022",
                Number = "4012001037141112",
                Cvc = "123" ) )
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are doing idiomatic F# you would model this with [Records](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/records/) instead of [classes](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/classes/).

You could do it like this:

```ml
type CreditCard = {
    ExpirationMonth: int;
    //More
}

type CustomerRequest = {
    Method: string;
    CreditCard: CreditCard;
}

let req = {
    Method = "Credit"
    CreditCard = {
        ExpirationMonth = 6
        //More
    }
}
```

The compiler has type-inference that means it can guess that `req` is a `CustomerRequest` by the fields you have in it, and the same for the `CreditCard` - you can hint the type if you really need to.

If you really are after classes - perhaps you have to interop with C# code, then you would do it like this:

```ml
type CreditCard2(expirationMonth:int) = 
    member this.ExpirationMonth = expirationMonth

type CustomerRequest2(method: string, creditCard: CreditCard2) = 
    member this.Method = method
    member this.CreditCard = creditCard

let req2 = CustomerRequest2 ("Credit", CreditCard2 (5))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for:

CreditCard.fs

```
namespace StackOverflow

type CreditCard() =
    member val ExpirationDate = "" with get, set
    member val ExpirationYear = "" with get, set
    member val Number = "" with get, set
    member val Cvc = "" with get, set

type CustomerRequest() =
    member val Method = "" with get, set
    member val CreditCard = new CreditCard() with get, set
```

Program.fs

```
open System
open StackOverflow

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let body = new CustomerRequest(Method = "CREDIT_CARD",
                                        CreditCard = CreditCard(
                                            ExpirationDate = "06",
                                            ExpirationYear = "2022",
                                            Number = "4012001037141112",
                                            Cvc = "123"
                                        ))
    0
```

I do not know much about F# so maybe using Records like David Shaw uses is better design wise. But basically this will let you do it without a parameter constructor and without a mutable non property value in your type.

Comment: Thank you for your help

Comment: Looking at your code: `CreditCard = new CreditCard`, Need the `new` command?

Comment: @MatheusMiranda It appears that you do not. I will edit the answer.